# How to increase the size of the graph while maintaining the relative scale of its elements

Tags: r, graph, tiff, save

I am required to produce publication graphs for a publication, however I have trouble scaling up the graphs while maintaining the relative size of its elements.

The publisher requires

```
Submit the image as TIFF, at one of the following resolutions:
Color: 300 dpi
Grayscale: 600 dpi
Line art: 1200 dpi
Text-based graphics should be provided as 300 dpi, close-cropped TIFFs, sized to match print.
To maximize the size of the figures on the PDF/reprint, figures should be submitted at the width of 2 columns (about 6.75 inches, 40 picas wide).
```

For example

```
tiff(filename="Test1.tiff",width=400,height=400)
plot(c(2,2,4,4), c(2,4,2,4),xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,10), xlab="Text xlab", ylab="Test ylab", pch=16, cex=1.5)
polygon(c(2,2,4,4),c(2,4,4,2), col="darkblue")
text(1,8,"Test")
dev.off()

tiff(filename="Test2.tiff",width=1200, height=1200)
plot(c(2,2,4,4), c(2,4,2,4),xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,10), xlab="Text xlab", ylab="Test ylab", pch=16, cex=1.5)
polygon(c(2,2,4,4),c(2,4,4,2), col="darkblue")
text(1,8,"Test")
dev.off()
```

In this example Test 2 is larger (as graph area) however the axis and labels appear much much smaller. How can I correct this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the resolution of the tiff file. So try something like:

```
ppi = 300
tiff("mygraph.tiff", width=6.75*ppi, height=6*ppi, res=ppi)
plot(c(2,2,4,4), c(2,4,2,4),xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,10), 
      xlab="Text xlab", ylab="Test ylab", 
      pch=16, cex=1.5)
polygon(c(2,2,4,4),c(2,4,4,2), col="darkblue")
text(1,8,"Test")
dev.off()
```

However, most (all?) journals also accept postscript or pdf formats. For line graphs, use these vector formats. Using a vector format means that the graph will scale perfectly, unlike raster formats.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, not all journals accept EPS. Where did the factor 6.75 and 6 at the width and height option respectively come from?

Comment: The 6.75 came from your question "6.75 inches wide". The 6 is just my standard default ;)

Answer (score 0):

To maintain default pointsize of plotted text, scale pointsize by 9/5 of desired height.

Default pointsize = 12 points, where 1 point = 1/72 in

Default height = (480 pixels) / (72 ppi) = (480/72) in

Scaling factor = (12 points) / (480 pixels / 72 ppi) = (9/5) points/in

Following above example, with a desired height of 6 inches:

`tiff("mygraph.tiff", res=ppi, height=6*ppi, width=6.75*ppi, pointsize=6*(9/5))`